# how to remove line from fill scale legend using geom_vline and geom_histogram r ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, legend

Basics:
Using R statistical software, ggplot2, geom_vline, and geom_histogram to visualize some data. The issue is with the legend keys.

I'm trying to plot a pair of histograms from some stochastic simulations, and on top of that plot a couple of lines representing the result of a deterministic simulation. I've got the data plotted, but the legend keys for the histograms have an unnecessary black line through the middle of them. Can you help me remove those black lines? Some sample code reproducing the issue is here:

```
df1 <- data.frame(cond = factor( rep(c("A","B"), each=200) ), 
                 rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.8)))

df2 <- data.frame(x=c(.5,1),cond=factor(c("A","B")))

ggplot(df1, aes(x=rating, fill=cond)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, position="dodge") +
  geom_vline(data=df2,aes(xintercept=x,linetype=factor(cond)),
             show_guide=TRUE) +
  labs(fill='Stochastic',linetype='Deterministic')
```

[image]
Edit: added image

Cheers,
Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround is to change the order of `geom_histogram()` and `geom_vline()`. Then add another `geom_vline()` without `aes()`, just giving `xintercept=` and `linetype=`. This will not remove lines but will hide them under the color legend entries.

```
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=rating, fill=cond)) + 
  geom_vline(data=df2,aes(xintercept=x,linetype=factor(cond)),
             show_guide=TRUE) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, position="dodge") +
  geom_vline(xintercep=df2$x,linetype=c(1,3))+
  labs(fill='Stochastic',linetype='Deterministic')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! You've solved my problem. If you don't mind, could you explain why the lines were occurring in the fill keys to begin with? It seemed strange to me that the legend keys (red or green bars WITH black lines) didn't match the actual data (red or green bars with NO lines)

Comment: I am not sure way this happens but I assume that somehow is connected with geom_vline(). It happens even if I use data frame with different levels and names.

Comment: ggplot remains a beautiful mystery to me. Thanks again.

Comment: It might be worth submitting an `issue` regarding this. My guess is it could be a bug with `geom_vline` and `show_guide`, or there needs to be more documentation on `guides`