# Legend showing an unexpected black line with geom_vline

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have been trying to add an additional legend after looking at some of the answers provided at StackOverflow but somehow I can't make this work. I'm using the following code:

```
 x_breaks <- seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2015/4/1"), "months")
    x_labels <- as.character(x_breaks, format="%b%y")

    vLines <- data.frame('Date'=as.Date('2014/1/1'))
    vLines <- rbind(vLines,vLines,vLines,vLines)
    vLines$Date[1] <- as.Date('2010/6/7')
    vLines$Date[2] <- as.Date('2012/1/1')
    vLines$Date[3] <- as.Date('2012/10/1')
    vLines$Date[4] <- as.Date('2013/1/1')

    vLines$grp <- c('Complex Cases','Breach of Contract Cases','PI, PD and WD cases','All other civil cases')  

    p <- ggplot(toPlot[1:296,], aes(x=Date, y=value, fill=OrderType)) + scale_x_date(breaks=x_breaks, labels=x_labels) +
  geom_area(stat="identity",alpha=0.6) +
#   scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  ggtitle('Some Title') + theme_bw() + ylab('Transactions') + xlab('') +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(hjust=0, angle=0), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1, angle=45),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x=element_line(color='grey90',linetype='dashed'),
        panel.grid.major.y=element_line(color='grey90',linetype='dashed'),
        plot.title=element_text(size=20),
        axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        legend.text=element_text(size=20),
        legend.key=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#a6cee3","#1f78b4","#b2df8a","#33a02c","#fb9a99","#e31a1c","#fdbf6f","#ff7f00","#cab2d6","#6a3d9a")) +
  geom_vline(data=vLines,aes(xintercept=as.numeric(Date),color=grp,linetype=grp),size=1,show_guide=TRUE)
p
```

to get the following plot:
[image]

The output of `dput(head(toPlot))` is:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(14853, 14914, 15034, 15187, 
15309, 15340), class = "Date"), OrderType = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Delivery", "eFiling", "Filing", 
"ProcessServing", "Research"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Orders", "Revenue"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 18, 37)), .Names = c("Date", "OrderType", 
"variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I remove this black ugly line from the legend?

**The dataset that I'm using may be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1snBnrJbhgda1vH4fNsdrLfchMSD0dDc4rfoPdBFu6ks/edit?usp=sharing).**

Any pointers on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why ggplot is adding black vertical lines to the fill legend. However, you can get rid of them by adding this to your plot code:

```
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA)))
```

Comment: This did not work for me. However, the following worked for me: show.legend = FALSE. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40264605/3142890 for more.

Answer (score 3):

<s>What about `show_guide=FALSE` in:</s>

```
geom_vline(data=vLines,aes(xintercept=as.numeric(Date),color=grp,linetype=grp),size=1,show_guide=FALSE)
```

As @eipi10 mentioned in the comment this solution doesn't work in this case, because it will hide also the vline legend.

When `ggplot` draws a legend it tries to use all possible properties (fill, color, linetype), so drawing the `fill` legend you get also the `vline` lines properties (color and linetype).

What can you do? As you can see in the @eipi10's answer you can add a guides command to tell to ggplot that for the fill scale the colour property (the one used by the vline legend) has to be invisible (NA).

```
guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA)))
```

But you can achieve the same adding the guide in 'scale_fill_manual':

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#a6cee3","#1f78b4","#b2df8a","#33a02c","#fb9a99","#e31a1c","#fdbf6f","#ff7f00","#cab2d6","#6a3d9a")), 
                    guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour=NA)) +
```

Another solution would be to draw the `geom_area` after `geom_vline`, as suggested here: [how to remove line from fill scale legend using geom_vline and geom_histogram r ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943094/how-to-remove-line-from-fill-scale-legend-using-geom-vline-and-geom-histogram-r)

This is a nice solution, you can try also to do it without plotting twice the `vline`, but this won't work very well in your case because you have the `alpha=0.6` value. So also for this solution you need to use `override.aes`, having something like this:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#a6cee3","#1f78b4","#b2df8a","#33a02c","#fb9a99","#e31a1c","#fdbf6f","#ff7f00","#cab2d6","#6a3d9a"),
                    guide=guide_legend(override.aes=list(alpha=1))) +
geom_vline(data=vLines,aes(xintercept=as.numeric(Date),color=grp,linetype=grp),size=1,show_guide=TRUE)+
geom_area(stat="identity",alpha=0.6)
```

Or invert the two `geom` and add:

```
guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(alpha=1)))
```

I wrote this just because I spent some time trying to figure out this problem, why to use the `guide_legend(override.aes)` and if there are other solutions. Writing was a good way to this settle down.

Comment: That get's rid of the vertical line in the `fill` legend but also removes the vline color legend.

Comment: Yes, that removed the legend too.

Comment: I saw it and I tried to figure out if there are other solutions

Comment: @mucio - thanks a lot, that was very useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the chance to test this, but this may be a useful pointer for you. I usually start with the Zev Ross cheatsheet, and have modified some of the tips there to my first guess for removing shapes inside of the legend:

```
guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=NA)))
```

Source: http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/